# Can latex automatically update date on each section whenever I write in that section? Trying to use overleaf as a collaborative work journal

Tags: latex, overleaf, journal

Me and my team is using overleaf to keep track of our work progress. Basically I send queries and whoever has solution posts on overleaf as a sub section. I want all of this back and forth queries and solutions sections to have the date when they were posted. Is it even possible?

I am a beginner in Latex and tried
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
But I think it is for the whole document not for each section.